# How to make a read-only data connection to a read-write locked MS Access using MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access, multiple-users

My concern is that there is a read-write lock in the file I want to connect to because it is being used by an application as shown:
[Locked MS Access File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwxBO.png)

When I try to refresh the data connection in MS Excel, these errors/notifications occur because it is unable to make a connection to the MS Access file that is being used:

[image: 1st]

[image: 2nd]

[image: 3rd]

[image: 4th]

I am wondering if there is an option in MS Access that will `deny write` only but `allow read` or something that will allow me to establish a `read-only data connection` to my MS Excel file even though it is locked.

I have found `record-level locking` options in the MS Access file, but i'm concerned it may cause problems to the users of the main application that is writing data to the MS Access file. I tried disabling it but it's still locked. The options are shown:
[Record-level locking options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQjKb.png)

The connection string of my Excel data connection to a Access file is shown below:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
User ID=Admin;
Data Source=C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Test.MDB;
Mode=Share Deny Write;
Extended Properties="";
Jet OLEDB:System database="";
Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";
Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;
Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;
Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;
Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;
Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";
Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;
Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;
Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;
Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False
```

Comment: Are you comfortable with VBA to establish the Read only connection from Access to Excel?

Comment: Yes I am quite comfortable with VBA. If you have a solution it'll be appreciated

Comment: Okay wait let  first let me tets the Code !

Comment: To set the Mode either set the Connection Mode property or the Connection string.

`db.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\test.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;Mode=Read;"`  Check this if clicked for you then I'll post it as answer.

Comment: **Cont..** other should be you could store the Databasee in a shared folder where the other users have read-only permission. Then they should still be able to view, but not change, the data in the linked table.

Comment: @RajeshS I have placed my connection string in the main post I am unsure where to place that should I replace the `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;` in the first line of my connection string to `db.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may use this VBA to connect the Access database in Read Only mode:*

```
Sub ReadFromAccess()
    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object
    Dim intColIndex As Integer
    Dim DBFullName As String
    Dim TargetRange As Range

    DBFullName = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Sample.mdb"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set TargetRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";" & "Persist Security Info=False;Mode=Read;"

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM Table Name", cn, , , adCmdText

    For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    TargetRange.Offset(1, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
    Next

    TargetRange.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- *File path C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Sample.mdb* and *Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")* are editable.
- Instead of *DBFullName* variable you could use File path
  *C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Sample.mdb*, as I've shown in comments.

.

Comment: Awesome. I'll try it out tomorrow :).

Comment: I have a syntax error to this one line: `cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";" Persist Security Info=False;Mode=Read;"`

Comment: Okay I think I found the error. The line should be: `cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";" & "Persist Security Info=False;Mode=Read;"` just lacked an ampersand and semi-colon in string concatenation

Comment: Good code this is a life saver

Comment: @Pherdindy,  glad to help you,, keep asking ☺

Comment: @Pherdindy, Yes the & sign was missing now I've edited the post, thanks. ☺

Comment: Hi, i'm liking your code as it's the only solution I have at the moment. My concern is that I get this error: `"Method 'CopyFromRecordset' of object 'Range' failed"` on other computers while on some it works perfectly. Do you know what causes this error?

Comment: @Pherdindy,, may possible  the Recordset (data)You retrieve includes Null values. Just  Check & confirm it?

Comment: @Pherdindy, perhaps Database has  very long string in column, the RecordSet retrieves from any MEMO data type may alos generates this  error.

Comment: Thank you will look at the data provided by the database. It's weird it works on other computers but not on some of them